# I've been trying to create the button to navigate to the second page but somehow the RaisedButton function did't work out

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have been following the yt video on creating the navigation map button but I don't understand what did I do wrong on RaisedButton line (I put in stars infront and at the back)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ionicons/ionicons.dart';
import 'package:avenique/pages/PlanningPaymentScreen.dart';

class RootApp extends StatelessWidget {
  RootApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print("menu pressed");
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu)),
        title: Text("PlanningPage"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("search pressed");
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
     **   child:RaisedButton(  **
            child: Text(
              'Next Screen',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
              ),
              ),
              Color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => PlanningPaymentScreen()),
                );
              }),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

I expected the code to run smoothly. Thankyou for the help!

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `RaisedButton` is deprecated. try using " `ElevatedButton` " and you will find a function inside then you can push.

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
}
```